# Prevent file deletion in Android

Tags: android

My app will be writing some files to the storage which will be used by the app when in use (like a config). This config is time dependent and will be replaced by app when required.

Currently, I am writing this to the sdcard using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). But this is visible when user used a file browser and could be deleted.

Is it possible for me to prevent the file deletion except by the application itself?

I tried using Environment.getDataDirectory()  but i do not have permission to write there. Is there an other way?

Comment: Use internal storage. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: As you can't. Even if you write your files in Internal Storage root user can easily access those files.

Comment: You must explain what do you want to achieve. Prevent file from deleting is not possible on sdcard. This is because of vfat filesystem which is used for external storage on android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Instead of saving in public location like SD card, write your file in application private space (internal storage), like:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("myfile.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write( WebnetTools.serializeObject( sec ) );
fos.close();
```

[See docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29) for more details. Be avare, that it is NOT equivalent of SD card due to **limited** space you got there.

Answer (score 0):

If writing to the SD card is not a requirement, you can [write to the phone's internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) to make the data private to your application.

Answer (score 0):

I used android:sharedUserId in the android manifest and now is able to write across the app's internal memory.

As my only purpose is to write text files (no sharing etc is involved), I found this the most easiest to implement.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
File folder = context.getDir("images", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        File img = new File(folder, "img_"+widget_id+"_"+position+".png");
        try{
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(img);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            b.recycle();
            internal_img = img.getPath();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

getDir create a folder on internal memory you can write all you want inside cause no way to prevent deletion on SD card. Also if sd card is unmount you can't read/write your files